# Can someone help me pinpoint my Javascript error for a simple Ajax request using Google Street Map API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm not too familiar with Javascript but I'm following along with a Udacity tutorial to learn more about Javascript and Ajax. Below I have the following code that is supposed to grab an image from google street view api and then append that image onto the body. Here is the code:

```
function loadData() {

    var $body = $('body');
    var $wikiElem = $('#wikipedia-links');
    var $nytHeaderElem = $('#nytimes-header');
    var $nytElem = $('#nytimes-articles');
    var $greeting = $('#greeting');

    // clear out old data before new request
    $wikiElem.text("");
    $nytElem.text("");

    // load streetview

    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE!
    var $streetInput = $('#street').val();
    var $cityInput = $('#city').val();
    var $googleStreetUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x600&location=' + $streetInput + ' ' + $cityInput

    $.ajax($googleStreetUrl, {
        success: function() {
            $body.append("<img class='bgimg'>").attr('src', $googleStreetUrl);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('wrong!');
        }
    });

    return false;
};

$('#form-container').submit(loadData);

// loadData();
```

The ajax request works just fine if I only have this code for $.ajax();

```
$.ajax($googleStreetURL);
```

The problem is the success/error part? Is this not how an ajax call is supposed to be sent. I looked at the MDN docs and from what I read this should be correct. Or maybe its a syntax error? I don't know because Sublime Text doesn't tell me if there is anything wrong with my javascript (except of course my semicolons). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $googleStreetUrl
```

is an image url, why are you using $.ajax to get the file? Just assign your image tag's src parameter the value of that variable.

Comment: Aren't I supposed to request the image from Google using the API? I've already tried just doing  $body.append("<img class='bgimg'>").attr('src', $googleStreetUrl); but without the server response I don't have anything to set the src of the image to.

Comment: You're not using the server response. In the success function you should have success: function(serverResponse). But that url doesn't respond with anything but an image, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer with some more code. Are you saying all I need is this then:

var $streetInput = $('#street').val();
var $cityInput = $('#city').val();
var $googleStreetUrl = long google map api url

$body.append("<img class='bgimg'>").attr('src', $googleStreetUrl);

I've tried this and nothing happens whatsoever.